# Cannot find id with R.id

Tags: java, android

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`TextView` has in id of `myText` and from my Java file I am trying to access this view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);  // here
    myTextView.setText("New Text in Text View");
}
```

But that `myText` has red color font meaning it is not resolved.

Why is this so? How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

My imports:

```
package ru.startandroid.androidlessons;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

I was following some tutorial and created lots of modules in one project. So, I got confused and created layouts in one module and tried to access it from another module's java file. So, **using the right java file did it**

But I was still unable to import `R.java` of another module. Is that possible? or restricted?

Module name: `p0061_layouts`, Package name: `ru.startandroid.layouts`

Comment: Are you importing the right R file? You should import com.packagename.R, not android.R

Comment: Remove it and have it built all new again. Sometimes it won' t update correctly.

Comment: could you please post the imports too..

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've imported android.R instead of your library.
It happens to me sometimes in Eclipse :-)

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) if it work its mean android.R is not imported :)\

Answer (score 2):

if `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` worked? then their may be have some mistake first of all use 
`TextView` instead of `View`

if still have same error manually clean your project then try if you are using eclipse in menu bar **project-> cleanproject** and check **`automatically build`**